# GLFW not finding monitors

Tags: c++, glfw

I've been working on a project and using GLFW as a windowing system. Recently, I tried to implement full screen. From reading the documentation, I've figured out that you need to call glfwCreateWindow() with the fourth parameter being the monitor you want to have the window full screen on. I did something like this:

```
glfwInit();
...

glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "MyWindow", glfwGetPrimaryMoniter(), nullptr);

...
```

But the window wasn't full screen. After some testing I determined that glfwGetPrimaryMoniter() was returning 0. I don't know if it matters but I'm on a laptop with windows 10. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: [Check if an error occured](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro.html#error_handling)

Comment: I already tried an error callback, never got called

Comment: @DrCoco I Know is late, but check my answer if you need this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call GLContext.createFromCurrent() after making the context of the window.

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); 
GLContext.createFromCurrent();
```